# Angular virtual scroll inside a dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to use angular virtual scrolling for performance issues, and if I put it normally on the website, it works fine, but as soon as I put it where I want it, which is inside a few nested `ul` and `li` tags, it no longer works.

This is the HTML:

```html
    <ul class="dropdown-menu context-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        test<i class="far fa-angle-right"></i>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="height: 220px">
          <li style="height: 200px">
            <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport class="example-viewport" itemSize="50">
              <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item}}</div>
            </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```css
.context-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    z-index: 1502 !important;
    min-width: 220px;
    left: -115px;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 170px;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.dropdown-menu-left {
    right: 100%;
    left: unset;
}

.example-viewport {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.example-item {
    height: 50px;
}
```

I'm guessing there is an issue with using dropdowns, that only appear when you hover on them.

The entire `ul` menu above appears when the user clicks on a button, and the `li` with the virtual scroll only appears once you hover on a specific item inside the `ul`.

How can I fix so that the virtual scroll will work normally?

I can scroll a few items up to item 3, then it starts scrolling into nothing. Below is an image of how it looks (the gray tint is because it is paused in the debugger):

[image]

**EDIT:** It appears that this happens when it is displayed in initially hidden components

Comment: Try setting a fixed height on the element containing `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`

Comment: @NilsKähler tried setting it on the ng-container (which I also tried removing) and on the parent ul, it does not help

Comment: The ng-container is not rendered, so that would not help. Perhaps try to wrap it in a li with a fixed height. You should only have li elements as direct children of ul elements.

Comment: @NilsKähler also tried that, edited the code, now it contains the exact code, which I am using (cut out a few parts, but the issue still persists).

Comment: Could you try setting `*cdkVirtualFor="let item of items; templateCacheSize: 0"`

Comment: @NilsKähler also did not seem to do anything

Comment: Try to create a component with the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`, that might clear up some of the problems, with nesting it inside other content.

Comment: @NilsKähler I have done that, and have tried using it in different parts of the application. Seems that if I use it in the main html it works fine, but once I put it somewhere, that is inside the router-outlet it no longer works as it should. EDIT: the other components also need to be loaded by the click of a button

Comment: @NilsKähler I have edited the post, I have discovered that this apparently happens when it is used in initially hidden components

Comment: Then it might be something that is a registered bug, try to do the recommended step in this [bug report](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24362).

Comment: @NilsKähler I have managed to "solve" it, but I don't think I'm happy with the solution. The component, where I'm trying to show it has the change detection strategy on push. A solution was to do a `setInterval(() => { this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); }, 0)` in the virtual scroll component, but I think that improve performance in loading, but degrade performance elsewhere, because it constantly detects changes?

Comment: Don't use `setInterval`, you should use `setTimeout`, since it should only run once. That might improve performance, the suggested fix, should only run when you change the size of the scroll-viewport, so when it's shown or changed in size in any way, so the performance should not be that bad.

Comment: @NilsKähler sadly, it does not work if I use `setTimeout`, it seems like it needs to constantly detect changes for it to actually work

Comment: It seems to work in this example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3aywjn?file=src/app/cdk-virtual-scroll-append-only-example.html

Comment: @NilsKähler Thank you, but it still does not seem to work. I have tried a different strategy now, which seems to work good performance wise. I used ViewChild on the virtual scroll and subscribed to the `elementScrolled` event, and when the event fires, I call `this.viewport.checkViewportSize()` and `this.changeDetector.detectChanges()`.